# add in how many items are in the cart

Tags: php

I can not get this part to work  I have even tried to change the `$key` to just `$k => $v` and it is not outputting what i need to to do. Should I be changing this line `$itemCount=X;` to `$itemCount=count()`??? At this point in time I have not a clue what else to do and its very fustating. Thanks for all whos look.

I need to add in how many items are in the cart

```
  if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']!="CART FILE"){
            echo "<h1>Cart Contents</h1>";
            echo "<div class=\"p2\">";
            $itemCount=X;
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$X)
            {
               for($i=0;$i<count($X);$i++){
                  $itemCount+= $X;
               }
            }

            echo "<a href=\"cart.php\">You have ".$itemCount." total items in your cart.</a>";
            echo "</div>\n";
 }
} // End of while loop.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the PHP [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) method on your $_SESSION['cart'] variable and remove all the other code like your foreach. This should be fine:

```
 if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']!="CART FILE"){             
     echo "<h1>Cart Contents</h1>";             
     echo "<div class=\"p2\">";             

     echo "<a href=\"cart.php\">You have ".count($_SESSION['cart'])." total items in your cart.</a>";
 }
```

Comment: that doesnt really work it makes my other cart all on the bottom.

Comment: @st1984: of course you have to modify my example to meet your layout and styling requirements, but the count itself should work just fine. Glad I could help!

Comment: Thats what I had to do was add in the echo part that is there and it works fine now..Man somethings is coding can get confused. But thanks it helped me alot